# Global event handler in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not sure how should I handle event in my angular app.

I am setting some $rootScope property in my .run() function:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location',
    function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $location) {
        $rootScope.something = "something_";
    }
]);
```

My HTML looks like:

```
  <body class="dashboard" ng-app="app">

      <select name="active_project" id="active_project">
          <option value=""></option>
      </select>    
    <div id="content" ui-view></div>


  </body>
```

Now - when user changes the dropdown value (active_project) I want to change $rootScope.something value to new one.

How *should* I do such thing?

EDIT:
I don't want to make it in single controller. As you can see, this dropdown is OUTSIDE ui-view. So handler should be somewhere outside the controller. If not, I will be forced to handle this change in every single controller across the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to write a ng-change to update on change.
your html will become:

```
  <body class="dashboard" ng-app="app" ng-controller='myController'>

      <select ng-change='selectChanged()' ng-model='myModel' name="active_project" id="active_project">
          <option value=""></option>
      </select>    
    <div id="content" ui-view></div>


  </body>
```

You will also need to define a controller to listen to that change:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function(scope, rootScope){
    scope.selectChanged = function(){
        rootScope.something = scope.myModel;
        alert(rootScope.something);
    }
}]);
```

I have also added a link to a functioning [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/vfpnmqnx/).

After having given you the solution, I would like to add it is not a good idea to have value in rootscope. If you post what you are trying to achieve may be somebody here can guide you better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do i need controller for it? What if I have 10 controllers? Do I have to repeat myself in every controller? I want to handle this change everywhere.

Comment: if you have 10 controllers and you have only one select being accessed in 10 controllers is bad design. if you have 10 controller n 10 select all changing one global value again bad design. 10 controllers 10 select changing 10 global values also bad design. 

if you still need to do it then you can wrap your select in a directive that takes the rootscope parameter that u wanna update. it would be neater.

but i would advice you to share ur intent behind this so that we can help you better.

Comment: I want to have ONE select available everywhere.
Because I use router to assign controllers to paths, I also need a way to also change it in another place.

Comment: so basically what u need is to ensure that whatever value is selected in the select is available accross. if that is the case u can bind 'something' of rootscope to ng modal of the select. define ng change at one place n do a  rootscope.broadcast if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-selected` with a function assigning the select `ng-model` to the `$rootScope`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5r7wy5r/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="dummy">
    <select name="active_project" ng-selected="selectIt()" ng-model="somethingFromSelect" id="active_project">
          <option value="hello">hello</option>
          <option value="world">world</option>
    </select>
    {{something}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location',
    function($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.something = "";
    }
]);
app.controller('dummy', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function ($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.selectIt = function () {
        $rootScope.something = $scope.somethingFromSelect;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Do i need controller for it? What if I have 10 controllers? Do I have to repeat myself in every controller? I want to handle this change everywhere.